# Execute an AWS command in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, amazon-ec2

I execute an EC2 command through eclipse like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String spot = "aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --instance-types"
            + " m3.medium  --product-description \"Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)\"";
    System.out.println(spot);
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    final Process process = runtime.exec(spot);

    //********************
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader (isr);

            String line;
            while((line = buff.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.print(line);

}
```

The result in eclipse console is:

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --instance-types m3.medium  --product-description "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)"
{    "SpotPriceHistory": []}
```

However, when I execute the same command (`aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --instance-types m3.medium  --product-description "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)"`) in shell I obtain a different result.

> ```
> "Timestamp": "2018-09-07T17:52:48.000Z", 
>         "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1f", 
>         "InstanceType": "m3.medium", 
>         "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
>         "SpotPrice": "0.046700"
>     }, 
>     {
>         "Timestamp": "2018-09-07T17:52:48.000Z", 
>         "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a", 
>         "InstanceType": "m3.medium", 
>         "ProductDescription": "Linux/UNIX", 
>         "SpotPrice": "0.047000"
>     }
> ```

My question is: How can obtain in eclipse console the same result as in shell console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not getting the expected output because you are passing a console command through your Java code which is not getting parsed properly, and you are not utilizing the AWS SDKs for Java instead. 
To get the expected output in your Eclipse console, you could utilize the DescribeSpotPriceHistory Java SDK API call in your code[1]. An example code snippet for this API call according to the documentation is as follows:

```
AmazonEC2 client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().build();
DescribeSpotPriceHistoryRequest request = new DescribeSpotPriceHistoryRequest().withEndTime(new Date("2014-01-06T08:09:10"))
        .withInstanceTypes("m1.xlarge").withProductDescriptions("Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)").withStartTime(new Date("2014-01-06T07:08:09"));
DescribeSpotPriceHistoryResult response = client.describeSpotPriceHistory(request);
```

Also, you could look into this website containing Java file examples of various scenarios utilizing the DescribeSpotPriceHistory API call in Java[2]. 
For more details about DescribeSpotPriceHistory, kindly refer to the official documentation[3].

## References

[1]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#describeSpotPriceHistory-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeSpotPriceHistoryRequest-

[2]. https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.SpotPrice

[3]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSpotPriceHistory.html